# Sharing Razor views between several projects on the same solution

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I've got a solution that has 2 ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects and some of the views (cshtml files) are the same for both projects. I've tried sharing them by adding links on one of the projects (add -> existing item -> select the view from the other project -> add as link so that it references the same physical file). I can edit the file from project 2 (and yes,it does change the physical file as expected), but whenever I try to deploy the 2nd project (dotnet publish --self-contained...), it won't generate the project_name.views.dll assembly with the view. However, if I do add the files (copy from project 1), I do get the views assembly with the views.

[image: Views added as reference instead of being copied from the other project]

Any clues on why adding the file as link won't generate views assembly?

thanks.

Comment: Why not move the shared views to a class library that both projects share?

Comment: Please check if you set **Build Action** to `Content` for the .cshtml files that you added.

Comment: Hello. Yes, that was it. it got added to the csproj as <None  .../> instead of <Content .../>. Please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark is as correct.

Comment: Hi @LuisAbreu, glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. And I add it as an answer, hoping it can help other community members quickly fix similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> adding the file as link won't generate views assembly

As mentioned in my comment, to fix it, we can set **Build Action** to `Content`.

[image]

*In .csproj file*

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\ProjectName\Views\Home\Test.cshtml" Link="Views\Home\Test.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Besides, as @HMZ suggested, we can put shared views in a [Razor class library project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that can be packaged and reused.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that whern you
return view()
if you enter the name of view it will search in the view folder in this application
but you can do it by putting your full path in the return view("./../~/name of folders/viewName.cshtml")
but not recommended because  it is not maintainalble and reusable

Comment: But the problem is that the views aren't being precompiled by the razor compiler if they're referenced from VS as link (instead of being copied there!)